# Complex Analysis: image of $\mathbb{D}$ under $z+\frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The context is the following questions with 2 parts:

1. Define $f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z}$. Show that f is injective on {|z| < 1} and {|z| > 1}. Determine its image.
2. Write 1/f as a rational function to see that it maps $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{(-\infty, -\frac{1}{2}] \cup [\frac{1}{2}, \infty)\}$ in a biholomorphic way.

Here's what I came up with:

First of all part one, we show that $z+\frac{1}{z}$ is injective on $\mathbb{D}$. For this we simply set

$$\frac{z^2+1}{z} = \frac{w^2+1}{w} \\
\Leftrightarrow (z-w)(wz-1) = 0
$$ and see that this is not possible for $z \neq w$ and $wz \neq 1$.

Additionally, at 0 we have a pole of order 1.

For the second part we can look at what the mapping 1/f does to $z \in \partial \mathbb{D}$. It sends it to $\frac{1}{2 Re z}.$ This means $\partial \mathbb{D}$ is mapped to $\{(-\infty, -\frac{1}{2}] \cup [\frac{1}{2}, \infty)\}$

Now, I assume $z+\frac{1}{z}$ maps $\mathbb{D}$ to $\mathbb{\hat{C}}\setminus\partial\mathbb{D}$, but I need help proving this.

**Edit:** Reworked the entire question to include context and my progress.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Any own thoughts, too.

Comment: Hi Martin, thank you for the answer and I want to apologize for being so blunt. I have edited the original question and provided some context.

Comment: You should be able to use the previous parts, and the fact that $\frac{z}{z^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{f(z)}$.

Comment: Just curious for your first part, you need to be a little more explicit about $z=0$.

Comment: Hi Theo, I reworked my entire question and found out where exactly I need help. I need help finding the image of z+1/z. Would you mind taking another look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image of $f$ is $\Bbb{C}$. If we take any $\omega \in \Bbb{C}$, then
\begin{align*}
&\omega = f(z) = z + \frac{1}{z} \\
\iff \, &z^2 - \omega z + 1 = 0 \text{ and } z \neq 0 \\
\iff \, &z^2 - \omega z + 1 = 0,
\end{align*}
since $z = 0$ is clearly never a solution to $z^2 - \omega z + 1 = 0$. But, this is a complex quadratic, which will always have a solution, so the equation $\omega = f(z)$ also will always have a solution. Moreover, there will only be at most two solutions.

Another feature of $f$ is that $f(z) = f(1/z)$ for all $z \neq 0$. This says to me that $f(\Bbb{D}) = f(\Bbb{C} \setminus \overline{\Bbb{D}})$, as $z \in \Bbb{D}$ if and only if $1/z \in \Bbb{C} \setminus \overline{\Bbb{D}}$.

Note also that, if a solution $z = z_0$ to $f(z) = \omega$ lies on $\partial \Bbb{D}$, then the other solution, $1/z_0$, will also lie on $\partial \Bbb{D}$. If there were another solution in $\Bbb{D}$, there would be yet another solution in $\Bbb{C} \setminus \overline{\Bbb{D}}$, which would make $3$ solutions to the quadratic equation $f(z) = \omega$. This is a contradiction, hence
$$\emptyset = f(\Bbb{D}) \cap f(\partial \Bbb{D}) = f(\Bbb{C} \setminus \overline{\Bbb{D}}) \cap f(\partial \Bbb{D}).$$
Thus, $f(\Bbb{C})$ is partitioned by $f(\Bbb{D}) = f(\Bbb{C} \setminus \overline{\Bbb{D}})$ and $f(\partial \Bbb{D})$, and so
$$f(\Bbb{D}) = f(\Bbb{C}) \setminus f(\partial \Bbb{D}) = \Bbb{C} \setminus f(\partial \Bbb{D}).$$
As you surely can see,
$$f(z) = 2\operatorname{Re}(z)$$
for $z \in \partial{\Bbb{D}}$, which means that $f(\partial \Bbb{D}) = [-2, 2]$, so
$$f(\Bbb{D}) = \Bbb{C} \setminus [-2, 2].$$
The reciprocal of this function will just reciprocate the complex numbers in this range, yielding the desired result.

Comment: Surely the image is $C_ \infty$?

Comment: @copper.hat Yes. I was writing as though the domain is $\Bbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ (including removing $0$ from $\Bbb{D}$). I probably should have made that clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I can understand this solution. It really didn't occur to me that $f(z)=f(\frac{1}{z})$.